# supportmapfragment in android library

Tags: android, google-maps, android-library, supportmapfragment

I am trying to implement a fragment with SupportMapFragment as child fragment in an Android library but failed.
Things I've done are listed below:
1. Use SupportMapFragment in an Activity in the application -- Succeed
2. Use SupportMapFragment in a Fragment in the application -- Succeed
3. Added package name shown in library manifest in the [API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com) with SHA key
4. Moved 
    from application manifest to library manifest. 
5. Moved the Fragment using SupportMapFragment from application into library.
After 3, 4 and 5, an error I have in the logs appears to be same as the very common issue in [CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-maps-fragment-guide#troubleshooting)
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see developers_google_com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console 
           Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
           Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
            API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
            Android Application (;): SHA Key
I don't think I have same problem described there.

I am thinking it's by design SupportMapFragment can't be authorized within an android library. But could not find more reference for it.

Appreciated any solution for implementing SupportMapFragment in Android library or knowledge why this approach is not possible.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @dazza5000 No I forgot what I did and also didn't check for updates

Comment: I think we needed a key for the google maps api in the AndroidManifest.xml, but I don't remember what I did either ;)